# ASP.Net MVC Application_BeginRequest Session threw an Exception

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an issue with MVC Application. This was a working code and now all of sudden after updating nuget package I'm getting this error. I'm working on an MVC 4 Application.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

in the above method when I add watch on sender object I see an exception

> Session = '((System.Web.HttpApplication)(sender)).Session' threw an exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException'

Can you guys please help me to resolve this?
[image]

Comment: What package did you upgrade? Are you sure nothing else has changed? Did you try to roll back you upgrade?

Comment: I upgraded all the installed package i have done this earlier as well but im not sure what caused this error